# Python tkinter giving me an error when I try to set me logo (GUI WINDOW)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

When I try to add an image and set it as my GUI window logo it gives me these errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meina Jia\PycharmProjects\guwindow\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    icon = PhotoImage(file='logo.jpg')
  File "C:\Users\Meina Jia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Meina Jia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "logo.jpg"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I already changed the file type using code.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("420x420")
window.title("Backrooms in A Nutshell")

icon = PhotoImage(file='logo.jpg')
window.iconphoto(True, icon)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter doesn't support the jpeg format.

Comment: never knew that that solved my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "logo.jpg"
```

Meaning. You cannot save image as and renamed it. There are now ways to fix. It is better use `png` format.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will need the Pillow Library.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("420x420")
window.title("Backrooms in A Nutshell")

icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('logo.jpg'))
window.iconphoto(True, icon)


window.mainloop()
```

Note: It is good practice to import a library directly:
Run

```
import tkinter
```

instead of

```
from tkinter import *
```

Comment: Well, I just used a simple answer up there and used a png image instead of importing a whole new library, and also the Note you said after I did it gave me 6 errors.

Comment: @Jason it would give you errors as you would need to supply the prefix of tkinter. before each use of a function. It is considered better practice to do the above to distinguish between when you are using external modules.